What is mispronounced as "kitten-muncher"?
In Henry Dunbar: The Story of an Outcast by Mary Elizabeth Braddon, set around 1850 and published 1864, we have the following:

The footman made no response to his parting civility, but stood watching him for a few moments, and then closed the door with a bang.


"Hif that's a spessermin of your Hinjun acquaintances, I don't think much of Hinjur or Hinjun serciety. But what can you expect of a nation as insults the gentleman who waits behind his employer's chair at table by callin' him a kitten-muncher?"

I assume that it is a mispronunciation, but I can't guess what is meant by "kitten-muncher".

Maybe from the Anglo-Indian word Khidmatgar?

Since my suggestion has been upvoted and no-one has offered another, I will turn it into an answer.
Since childhood I've known Edward Lear's poem The Cummerbund, in which he implies new meanings for a set of 'Anglo-Indian' words - the Cummerbund (a sash worn with men's evening dress) becomes a ferocious monster. The Kitmutgar (as he spells it) is implied to be some sort of trailing vine.
The real meaning of khidmatgar is an Indian servant who serves food at the table. The footman's "kitten-muncher" must be a garbled version of this word.
